# How to create a minimum working example to demonstrate difficulties with BibTex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

I am struggling with BibTex and I would like to post a question on this forum.

It is comical and tragical at the same time but I have difficulties even making a minimal working example to demonstrate my problem.

I tried:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} 
Citation\cite{IEEEhowto:IEEEtranpage}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}

\end{document}
```

but I get this error message:

```
(./example.bbl

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \end{thebibliography}
```

What should I add to my **BibTex** example so that it **at least compiles**?

Comment: Does `IEEEexample.bib` contain any entries? Note that the `thebibliography` environment is set as a list, which requires at least one `\item`, which could be why LaTeX produces the error (and hence my question).

Comment: @Werner Yes, it contains tens of entries. I just downloaded it from the IEEE webpage: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/

Comment: Okay, then delete `example.bbl` and try the compile sequence again: (pdf)latex > BibTeX > (pdf)latex > (pdf)latex. It could be that `example.bbl` was written without entries in it, and every time you call `\bibliography{IEEEexample}`, it first checks to see whether you already have a `.bbl` associated with the file. If so it uses it (which causes the error if it's not in the correct format). If it doesn't exist, then it writes stuff in the `.aux` that BibTeX can pick up and use in a subsequent call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's examine the `\bibliography` from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\bibliography#1{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}%
  \fi
  \@input@{\jobname.bbl}}
```

For a call like `\bibliography{IEEEexample}` inside `example.tex`, it writes `\bibdata{IEEEexample}` to `example.aux` (if you did *not* call `\nofiles`), and tries to include `example.bbl`. If `example.bbl` is faulty for whatever reason (a previous compilation that didn't contain any bibliography entries, perhaps corrupt, or something else altogether), then it could cause an error at this point. The best (and easiest) solution here is to start fresh and delete `example.bbl`.

`\@input@` will cope with this removal since it's defined as

```
\def\@input@#1{\InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}}
```

which includes a file only if it exists, otherwise it just prints out a message to the terminal saying the file doesn't exist (not creating an error).